# How to remove a preset on Sapling Tree Gen (Linux Mint)

Tags: add-on, sapling-addon

I created some tree presets using the sapling tree gen addon. But I want to remove the presets that I made. How can I remove them? My OS is linux mint cinnamon.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presets are stored in the `./scripts/presets` directory. In the [standard directory layout](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html), for Linux, that would be under `$HOME/.config/blender/2.xx` where XX is the version of Blender.

Go to that directory, find the subdirectory that corresponds to the add-on, probably `operator/add_curve_sapling` and remove the files representing the presets you just added. They'll be named `PRESETNAME.py`. Typically they'll be the most recently added files.

Comment: Thank you so much! Problem solved!

Comment: You're welcome.  You asked while I was working on presets for my addon so I happened to have all of the information handy.